# Canonical livepatch service stopped working

Tags: package-management, 20.04, canonical-livepatch

A few hours ago my Canonical Livepatch stopped working. I searched for the  solution and than decided to reinstall Canonical Livepatch. Now I am getting the following error:

```
Failed to enable Livepatch: cannot enable machine: cannot send request: 
  Post https://livepatch.canonical.com/api/machine-tokens: EOF
```

I could not find anything online about this problem so I'm posting. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Same here as well.

`error executing enable: cannot enable machine: bad server status 401 (URL: https://livepatch.canonical.com/api/machine-tokens) server response: unauthorized`

Answer (score 2):

After a while i was able to find a solution, so to speak. Well, sorta. Nevertheless, it works like a charm in my particular situation.

```
1) sudo canonical-livepatch disable
2) sudo snap remove canonical-livepatch
3) sudo cp /etc/machine-id /etc/machine-id.original
4) sudo cp /var/lib/dbus/machine-id /var/lib/dbus/machine-id.original
5) gedit /etc/machine-id 
(remove everything and save empty machine-id)
6) sudo systemd-machine-id-setup
```

reboot

```
7) sudo snap install canonical-livepatch
```

Now proceed to (https://auth.livepatch.canonical.com/) and obtain the token, then

```
8) sudo canonical-livepatch enable [your token]
```

Your livepatch should work from this point pretty stable and apply necessary updates.

> **Source:** [Canonical livepatch failed when I tried to enable token](https://askubuntu.com/a/1268814/354766)

Comment: I have tried your solution but it does not work in my case. This is what I have on my terminal after applying your solution: "canonical-livepatch 9.5.5 from Canonical✓ installed" and "Successfully enabled device. Using machine-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" but  also in Software & Updates there is: "Canonical Livepatch has experienced an internal error. Please refer to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Livepatch#CommonIssues for further information." and  Lifepatch status in the top bar have red exclamation mark.

Comment: Have you tried this one, for the instance?

`sudo canonical-livepatch refresh`

By the way, can you provide the output:
`sudo canonical-livepatch status --verbose`,
`systemctl status snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service`
and
`grep livepatch /var/log/syslog` (upload the results on https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/)
I myself have a little to no experience, but maybe i can work out something in the meantime.

Comment: I have tried refresh which gives me following output: sudo canonical-livepatch refresh
checking for patches
nothing to apply
kernel: 5.4.0-42.46-generic
patch state: ✗ the application caused a crash last time it was applied, check system logs with `journalctl -f -t canonical-livepatch`
patch version: 70.3

xxx@xxx:~$ journalctl -f -t canonical-livepatch
No journal files were found.                                                                                                 Anyhow here is the output:"https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/3x8yRBBvcx/" Thanks.

Comment: `canonical-livepatch[883]: System contains non-livepatch tainted modules.
 canonical-livepatch[883]: Module may have caused kernel crash! Not inserting module.
 canonical-livepatch[883]: To override this warning, remove /var/snap/canonical-livepatch/common/locks/livepatch_Ubuntu_5_4_0_42_46_generic_70_70.3`

Considering this lines, i presume, that you'll need to do as follows:

remove `livepatch_Ubuntu_5_4_0_42_46_generic_70_70.3` file.

I suggest you moving it or rename, just in case. Than reboot your pc.

Comment: Removed and changed name. Rebooted. Folder "/var/snap/canonical-livepatch/common/locks" is empty but after trying commands from your previous post i have same result as before:" Aug 31 10:10:23 tze canonical-livepatch[890]: during refresh: cannot apply patches: lock file "/var/snap/canonical-livepatch/common/locks/livepatch_Ubuntu_5_4_0_42_46_generic_70_70.3" already exists"

Comment: According to the line Aug 30 15:21:01 `tze canonical-livepatch[3020]: during refresh: cannot apply patches: cannot apply update: cannot execute finitModule syscall: operation not permitted` it's PROBABLY refers to SecureBoot issues explaning at (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Livepatch), but, frankly said, i lack the necessary knowledge about this situation. I suggest you fill the bug report at (https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-livepatch-client/+bug/1833566) or ask someone more experienced. I'm sorry for not able to be of any help.

Comment: Just few minutes ago I received 179,3 MB of update. Livepatch status in the top bar is safe (green) again. I guess it was some kind of bug. Thanks a lot for your help, I have learned few useful commands from your posts, Best wishes.